# Unmapped composite object using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I'd like to convert a SQL query we use into HQL (or, if not possible, a native query). Unfortunately I am having issues with a particular query that uses a join. Here's the query in   question:

```sql
SELECT  p.ExternalId, p.HiddenScore, h.Score WeeklyScore, p.Score AllTimeScore, (p.Victories + p.Defeats) AS MatchPlayed, CAST(p.Victories AS FLOAT) / (p.Victories + p.Defeats) AS Ratio
FROM Ygo..Arena_PlayerRegistry p
JOIN Ygo..Leaderboard_HighScoreWeekly h ON p.ExternalId = h.ExternalId
WHERE h.DateAdded BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-02'
    AND (p.Victories + p.Defeats) > 35
    AND h.Score > 0
ORDER BY WeeklyScore desc
```

I have tried the following (and a few variations thereof):

```
TypedQuery<LeaderboardPlayerPojo> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT new model.composite.arena.LeaderboardPlayerPojo(p.externalId, p.hiddenScore, h.score, p.score, (p.victories + p.defeats), p.victories / (p.victories + p.defeats)) " +
    "FROM ArenaPlayerRegistry p " +
    "JOIN LeaderboardHighScoreWeekly h " +
    "WITH h.externalId = p.externalId " +
    "WHERE h.dateAdded BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate " +
    "AND (p.victories + p.defeats) > 35 " +
    "AND h.score > 0 " +
    "ORDER BY h.score DESC"
    , LeaderboardPlayerPojo.class);
```

I get an exception saying `Path expected for join!`

Any suggestions are appreciated!

edit: Just to clarify, the `LeaderboardPlayerPojo` class only exists as a content holder for this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your JPQL as:

```sql
SELECT NEW model.composite.arena.LeaderboardPlayerPojo(p.externalId, p.hiddenScore, h.score, p.score, (p.victories + p.defeats), p.victories / (p.victories + p.defeats))
FROM ArenaPlayerRegistry p,
     LeaderboardHighScoreWeekly h
WHERE h.externalId = p.externalId
  AND h.dateAdded BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
  AND (p.victories + p.defeats) > 35
  AND h.score > 0
ORDER BY h.score DESC
```

Comment: Does a cartesian product work with 2 joins? (e.g. SELECT FROM X JOIN Y ON ... JOIN Z ON ...)

Does it have the same performance as a join?

Comment: This JPQL query should have the same performance as the SQL query in your question. It is equivalent to a query having a single inner join.